# Installation/update of Xcode 13.2.1 with minimal simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

There was a query on updating Xcode, when there is not much disk space([Unable to Update XCode: Not enough space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223546/unable-to-update-xcode-not-enough-space)). Mine is different, but may provide a solution to the above query. Unlike Visual Studio, Xcode doesn't give any option to selectively install the modules. Is there a way by which, one can install/update vanilla Xcode and later install/update the required simulators? This would greatly reduce the storage requirement for Xcode.
I am using MacOS Monterey 12.1 on a 2017 model Macbook Air.

Comment: You can certainly delete simulators at any time, to save space, and this is one of the first things I do after an update; but you cannot prevent them from being created initially. And of course they all exist also inside the Xcode download and you cannot prevent that. If you want this to work a different way, file a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I had upgraded the OS to Version 12.3 and made one more attempt to update my Xcode to 12.3. Voila! There wasn't any complaint on lack of disk space and the update was successfully carried out. I swear that I haven't carried out any interim disk-cleaning operation and it remained at 40 GB as ever.